# pfSense in disable all packet filtering mode allows web admin on WAN IP

Tags: firewall, router, pfsense

A while back, I had a fiber internet connection installed at my business with a number of public IPv4 addresses. The ISP provided two blocks of IP addresses: a "P2P" block which contains a gateway (a physical device at my site) and a "usable" block for the public IPv4 addresses I paid for.

The instructions from the ISP were that I needed a router so I set up a pfSense to route between the two blocks: the "P2P" as the WAN with the gateway specified and the "usable" block as the LAN. I figured simply disabling NAT would work to route between them but while this did work for outgoing connections, it didn't work for incoming on my "usable" IPs. I then discovered the "disable all packet filtering" mode under Advanced > Firewall & NAT and using that did the routing as desired.

Later, during a pen test exercise, I realized the web admin for pfSense is available on the WAN interface which makes sense since the firewall is disabled. This is, of course, undesirable. Is there anything I can do to prevent web access on the WAN interface in this configuration? Or disable the web admin entirely (as I can use the console for configuration)?

Comment: What is the point of complete disabling the firewall function? 
What do you mean by P2P IP block?

Comment: I have a feeling this is a X-Y question, and that NAT is the problem for you, not the firewall. Can you describe your setup in some detail, and explain why you need to disable the firewall?

Comment: @RomanK This is what a P2P IP block is: [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/yymcdx/why_do_isps_provide_p2p_ips/)

Comment: I suggest you ask a question about your actual problem. What was your config? What was not working? Did you add allow-rules?

Comment: @RomanK or perhaps this discussion of P2P on metro ethernet is more informative: [link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1234101-comcast-fiber-metro-service-gave-me-two-public-ip-blocks). I can use a physical router as the answers there suggest but I thought a pfSense would be easier initially.

Comment: But did you actually add firewall rules to let traffic through? We *know* how IPv4 routing works, the fact that your router has a /30 (or /31) is irrelevant. Tell us your config and setup. Focus on whats the problem. Assume that whomever answers you is competent and has a good understanding of routing and IPv4.

Comment: I have updated the question with a better explanation of the network topology. I also highly recommend checking out the spiceworks link in my previous comment which discusses how people made this work on SonicWall and Cisco routers.

Comment: You keep adding irrelevant info, but you don't answer my question about firewall rules. I'm aware of how routing works, and don't need more links to tell me that.

Comment: The term P2P in this context is not a networking terminology. If you are receiving a Public IP in /30 or larger subnet, doesn't make any difference. 
Disabling firewall doesn't make any sense neither. You are making uneducated assumptions and forming questions that cannot be answered.
Routing with NAT is all you need. If you want to expose any service, you can port forward. Disabling firewall is completely pointless.
If you are receiving two subnets from your ISP, which is unclear from your question, it is basic routing configuration. It still doesn't require disabling firewall.

Comment: @RomanK The P2P IP block terminology comes from the Comcast provided documentation. All of the IPs in both blocks are IPv4 publicly routable addresses hence the need to disable NAT so that I can use the multiple public IP addresses I have paid my ISP for. I never specified a subnet mask size for either block so I don't know why there are so many comments here stating that the mask doesn't matter. I'm well aware of that.

Comment: @cmshowers it doesn't look like you are trying solve your problem. Instead of proving how "correct" you are, try editing your question and provide relevant information. You can disable NAT; it doesn't mean you must disable firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that end up here looking for a way to configure or disable the nginx webConfigurator in pfSense, there is not a good way to do it at the time of this writing (as of pfSense 2.7.2). However, I have some hacky solutions that might interest you.

**Disable the webConfigurator**

From the shell, you can stop the webConfigurator with this command:

```
pkill -F /var/run/nginx-webConfigurator.pid
```

And then use the option 11 "Restart webConfigurator" on the console menu to get it running again when you need it. You could even edit the `/etc/rc.initial` script to add an option for "Disable webConfigurator" if you were so inclined.

**Make the webConfigurator only listen on certain interfaces**

Unfortunately, the nginx config for the webConfigurator is generated by some scripts so this process is even dirtier. The config file is generated by the function `system_generate_nginx_config` in `/etc/inc/system.inc`. You can make any edits in here you like that work in an nginx.conf but they will likely be wiped out by the next system update to pfSense. You probably want to modify the server block in the config generation code and you could set it to only listen on the IP you want but personally I added an `allow` rule for the IP I am connecting in from and then a `deny all` after that.

Comment: It sounds like you want to [disable NAT](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/nat/outbound.html#disabling-outbound-nat), not packet filtering.

Comment: @vidarlo Thanks! I have enabled the firewall and disabled NAT and have figured out what I was doing wrong. I'd post another answer explaining but the question has been closed preventing me from adding answers. The short version is that I had automatically created block rules on my LAN firewall for "RFC 1918 networks" and "reserved not assigned by IANA" which I (foolishly) assumed meant allow all others. But there is an implicit block all rule on the LAN side firewall that doesn't get listed.

Comment: You can edit your answer. And yes, default to deny is normal on firewalls. You create rules to allow what you want. This is [exactly what I suggested here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1150611/pfsense-in-disable-all-packet-filtering-mode-allows-web-admin-on-wan-ip/1153687?noredirect=1#comment1508857_1150611).

Comment: @vidarlo How about I edit the answer you posted and then I'll give you the credit for solving it? I believe you'll have to review the edits before it gets posted anyway so you'll have a chance to modify it. I'll include screenshots of my firewall rules and what have you.

Comment: Sure, but I still think it's better if you edit your answer :) Editing your own answer requires no approval either.

Answer (score 3):

Enable packet filtering and create firewall rules that drops unwanted traffic.

That's kinda the *purpose* of firewalls - dropping unwanted traffic.

Comment: Obviously, I won't accept this as an answer. You didn't make an effort to understand what a P2P IP block is or why I would be using "disable all packet filtering" in the first place.

Comment: Why is the size of the IP block relevant to how a firewall functions? Dropping traffic on port y destined for IP x is what PF is good at. And that *will* block web interface access externally...